# WebClient and Thread Local State, Spring

Tags: spring, webclient, thread-local

When our app receives an API call from an external source, we create some thread local context which is the context of our business logic. When the API call returns we clean up and delete the thread locals.
If out code calls a WebClient task, what would be the best practice for getting the same thread local context into the result thread when the WebClient receives its data?

Comment: There is no right answer here. There are 3 ways. 1) URL 2) Headers and 3) Body of request. Depends on your domain, app and what you are passing in.